# One more "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)"

Tags: php, parsing, syntax

Why is it saying "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'print' (T_PRINT)..."?

```
<?php 

//init
$pi = 3.14;
$radius = 15;
$theArea = 0;

//area = 2 pi R
$theArea = $pi * ($radius * $radius)

//output
print ("The area of a circle of radius ".$radius." is " . $theArea);

?>
```

Comment: `;` after `$theArea = $pi * ($radius * $radius)`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a semicolon for the statement before the `print`

```
//area = 2 pi R
$theArea = $pi * ($radius * $radius); //here
```

Also you can use `print` without the parenthesis, since it's a language construct.

```
print "The area of a circle of radius " . $radius . " is " . $theArea;
```

Unless you **really** want to

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, print works also without () :)

Comment: yep :) you're very welcome!